# how fix configure: error: Qt is not available when install wireshark?

Tags: ubuntu, wireshark

this is my problem:

```
cd '/home/james/Desktop/wireshark-2.0.2'
./configure

...

checking if profile builds must be generated... no
checking for Qt5Core - version >= 5.0.0... no
checking for QtCore - version >= 4.7.0... no

configure: error: Qt is not available
```

How to fix this? I want complete install wireshark from tar file.

Answer (score 1):

The way wireshark is configured it requires QT.  If cannot find it, either because some path is not right or Qt is not installed.

Solutions:

- Correct the search paths, or
- [Install QT](https://wiki.qt.io/Install_Qt_5_on_Ubuntu).

Start by [checking if Qt is installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/126141/how-do-you-find-out-which-version-of-gtk-is-installed-on-ubuntu).

Answer (score -2):

You need to install:

`sudo apt-get install qt-sdk`

in some case, do:

`sudo apt-get install qttools5-dev`

Comment: The QT install document does not show this is the correct method to install QT. Could you confirm whether this actual works? Also, this is more or less the same information already in the previous answer, your answer doesn't add anything meaningful or new to the conversation.

Comment: This is additional to comment above.